# Can iconv convert the 'symbol' encoding?

Tags: encoding, greek

I need to convert some files in greek that are encoded to be used with 'Symbol' font to Unicode. Can I use iconv for this? And if so, what is the name of encoding that is used in 'Symbol'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might possibly use the online converter found in this website:
[Symbol font to Unicode converter](http://www.snible.org/greek/symb2uni.html).

This article contains a long list of converters,
where the author "have gathered all the Greek font converters of which I am aware"
(but I wouldn't know which one to recommend):
[Greek Legacy Fonts to Unicode Converters](http://bibleandtech.blogspot.fr/2010/05/greek-legacy-fonts-to-unicode.html).

Otherwise, you will probably have to create your own conversion tool.

The article [Convert symbol to unicode](http://dodavinkeln.se/post/convert-symbol-to-unicode) deals mostly with HTML files that
represent, for example, the character `Ω` via :

```
<font face="symbol">W</font>
```

The article includes the source-code for a program that converts such HTML files,
written in some unidentified programming language.

Another such article is
[How to convert Symbol font to standard utf8 HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240030/how-to-convert-symbol-font-to-standard-utf8-html-entity).

Otherwise, one too-simple method might be to use some word-processor to just select
the text and change its font, but is probably too simple to work.

You might post a minimal example file that will help us understand what kind of conversion
is required.

Answer (score 1):

You might be in for a tough ride. In origin, Symbol used a non-standard character set that was essentially made up for the font, allotting characters to ASCII codepoints by visual similarity to Roman alphabet characters; there is a description of how that encoding maps to Unicode at http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/symbol.txt which you might find handy.

I imagine it might be tricky to persuade iconv to do what you want - you may have to resort to some scripting work to directly transcode each character.